# Python Bitwise Shift doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation, shift

Here is my code

http://pastebin.com/xRAS7qLH

This creates an infinite loop so don't run it.

```
        intMask = 0
        while(temp != 0):
            print bin(temp)[2:].zfill(32)
            temp = long(temp << 1)
            intMask += 1
```

When I look at the output it looks like this

```
11111111111111111111111100000000

111111111111111111111111000000000

1111111111111111111111110000000000
```

What I was expecting was something more like this

```
11111111111111111111111100000000

11111111111111111111111000000000

11111111111111111111110000000000
```

etc

There must be something different with python, or I need to typecast something? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not create an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and post that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's integers have arbitrary precision, which besides being difficult to spell, means that as you bit shift, it keeps getting bigger.  If you want to limit the size, you'd want to do something like

```
temp = long(temp << 1) & (0xffffffff)
```

which should zero out.

Edit: Specifically, the & does a bitwise AND; 0xffffffff (8 f's) is 32 1's (in binary) so anything within the 32 bits will be preserved; anything beyond will be set to zero).  For more details, you could do something like:

temp = long(temp << 1)
print "Before AND: ",bin(temp)
temp = temp & 0xffffffff
print "After AND: ", bin(temp)

Comment: OK that worked, but could you explain why? I don't understand why that works.

Comment: Also I found that instead of doing the while loop, I can do the following math.log( x ) / math.log (2), which gives me the same value

Comment: If you were trying to find the number of bits required, I would expect code golf has all sorts of "interesting" ways to do this